# SSLSocketFactory setting handshake timeout and socket properties

Tags: android, ssl

I have a protocol where there's a regular plain socket that gets upgraded to SSL/TLS. I need to be able to control the timeout for processing the SSL handshake as well as other parameters such as allowed protocols versions. (e.g. turn off SSLv3).

You can do all this except for the handshake timeout via `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`, you can call `createSocket(socket, host port, autoClose)`, set the additional settings on the returned `SSLSocket`, then call `startHandshake` to the handshake. But there doesn't appear to be any way to set the handshake timeout setting, and the default setting is rather small.

Never fear, `android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory` is here!, this allows you to control the handshake timeout setting, but it also changes the behavior of `createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose)` to do the actual handshake, so by the time you get your SSLSocket back from the factory its too late to doing anything else that would affect the handshake (like turn off SSLv3).

Is there some way to do both? I need to be able to do this on Api v8

(SSLContext/SSLParameters looks like it might be useful but is Api v9, but it also looks like SSLCertificateSocketFactory creates its own context, so setting the default one won't help).

Answer (score -1):

For specific protocol selection have you tried SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols before calling startHandshake?

For handshake timeout setting you can use SSLCertificateSocketFactory.

Comment: If you get the socket from SSLCertificateSocketFactory, which you need to do to set the timeout, it automatically calls startHandshake for you, so you don't get any chance to set the protocol on the socket instance.